# Getting started with Wubi

Tags: wubi

What are the advantages of using the Wubi installer? Can it be used for dual booting Windows XP 32-bit with  Ubuntu? Also is it possible to use Wubi for installing Ubuntu 32-bit version? A step-by-step explanation would be helpful.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

You can follow the following steps to get a successful Ubuntu installation using Wubi

**1.Setting the installer up**

[image: Wubi installer]

^^That is how your Wubi Installer would look. Set up a username, install location, password, language, size and you're ready for the next step.

**2.Downloading Ubuntu**

[image: Ubuntu download]

This is fairly easy, and the user (i.e. you), have no role to play in this. Wubi downloads all that is necessary whilst allowing you to carry out your required tasks on Windows.

**3.Completing the setup**

[image: setup complete]

Now that you have completed the setup, you need to reboot, do note, rebooting is necessary to complete the installation.

**4.Final**

[image: reboot screen]

This is how your screen should look post rebooting. Choose Ubuntu and you can boot into your fresh installation. Hope this helped!

*Note: These images do not belong to me I have taken them from this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)*

Comment: Thank you , but do I need to partition my hard disk first?Also it seems  Wubi by default downloads the 64 bit version of ubuntu, but my computer is of 32 bit................

Comment: No you don't need to partition your hard disk. To download the 32 bit version, download the iso manually, for example, if you've downloaded Wubi 13.10, download the 13.10 iso and place **both** in the same folder and then run Wubi.

Comment: @user220789 You also need to run `wubi.exe` with the `--32bit` argument if you're installing 32bit Wubi on a computer that has a 64bit chip (which yours does). This is a new requirement since they changed the kernel name on the 64bit ISO on newer releases.

Comment: My windows XP os is of 32 bits.How do i find out if it has a 64 bit chip?I am still a novice and don't know much about these things.@bcbc

Comment: @user220789, processor name and version?

Comment: Intel(R)Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7400 @2.80GHZ

Comment: @user220789, your processor supports 64 bit. to clarify you may check this [link](http://ark.intel.com/products/36500)

Comment: Ok,Thank you.So my processor supports 64 bit, now the question is whether I should install ubuntu 64 bit version or 32 bit version.One of my friends had told me that if I install through wubi I need the 32 bit version since my windows os  is of 32 bit format.However in a regular installation I may install 64 bit format but then drivers may create a problem. Please help

Comment: @user220789, you can go ahead with the 64 bit version. It doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: @user220789, if this answer solved your question, please check the gray tick symbol to accept it.